# c/c++: How to read a serialized graph (tree) from text file with tabulation?

Tags: c++, regex, serialization, graph, tree

I'm trying to read a structed data (like a graph or a binary tree) from a file, it is  saved in a human redable data (no XML) with indendation.

For example

```
       a
     /    \
    b      c
   / \    /  \
  d   e  f    g
```

is written as:

```
a
    b
        d
        e
    c
        f
        g
```

Is there some function in c++ to count number of consecutive occurence of the char '\t' from the start of line?
Should I use RegEx?
I need to count number of '\t' (if any) from begin of line to the first different char from '\t' .

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read a line with getline, then iterate through it checking each character for '\t':

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream infile("test.dat");    
    string line;
    while (getline(infile, line))
    {   
        cout << line << endl;
        int tab_cnt = 0;    
        for (int ix = 0; ix < line.size(); ++ix)
            if (line[ix] == '\t')
                ++tab_cnt;
        cout << tab_cnt << endl;
    }   
}
```

Comment: that for will count '\t' in the whole line, i need only at begin. :)
very helpfull.